# I have a class Component but I get this `createAnimatedComponent` does not support stateless functional components; use a class component instead

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello I'm currently working in app trying to implement a screen with animation but I receive this message createAnimatedComponent does not support stateless functional components; use a class component instead.  But my component is a class!

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import { Animated } from "react-native";

class Menu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    top: new Animated.Value(900),
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.spring(this.state.top, {
      toValue: 0,
    }).start();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AnimatedContainer style={{ top: this.state.top }}>
        <Cover />
        <Content />
      </AnimatedContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;

const Container = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
`;

  const AnimatedContainer = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Container);

const Cover = styled.View`
  height: 142px;
  background: black;
`;

const Content = styled.View`
  height: 900px;
  background: #f0f3f5;
`;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution!

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import { Animated, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

class Menu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    top: new Animated.Value(900),
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.spring(this.state.top, {
      toValue: 0,
    }).start();
  }

  toggleMenu = () => {
    Animated.spring(this.state.top, {
      toValue: 900,
    }).start();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AnimatedContainer
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          zIndex: "100",
          top: this.state.top,
        }}
      >
        <Row />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleMenu}>
          <CloseView>
            <Ionicons name="ios-close" size={40} color="#2457db" />
          </CloseView>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Col />
      </AnimatedContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;

const CloseView = styled.View`
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #fff;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const AnimatedContainer = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(View);

const Row = styled.View`
  height: 142px;
  background: #000000;
`;

const Col = styled.View`
  height: 900px;
  background: #eeeeee;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const AnimatedContainer = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Container);
```

`Menu` is a class, yes, but `Container` is not, and that is what you are passing to `createAnimatedComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert it to this

```js
const Container = styled(Animated.View)`
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
`;
```